# How to read certain lines into textbox using StreamReader?

Tags: vb.net

I have an assignment for school I need some help with.

I have made a program that you can input information about an employee and save that information to a .txt file.

Afterwards I have created a program that reads from that .txt files and shows the information in some textboxes.

I have three employees in my .txt file.

When I press the button "Next" in my latest program, I want it to show the next employee, and so on. It just shows information about the first and won't to to the next on the list.

How can I do that?

My code so far:

```
Dim EmployeeData As StreamReader


EmployeeData = File.OpenText("C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\Assignment 2-1\Assignment 2-1\bin\Debug\Test123.txt")


txtRecord.Text = (strFileName)
txtFirst.Text = EmployeeData.ReadLine()
txtMiddle.Text = EmployeeData.ReadLine()
txtLast.Text = EmployeeData.ReadLine()
txtID.Text = EmployeeData.ReadLine()
txtDepartment.Text = EmployeeData.ReadLine()
txtTelephone.Text = EmployeeData.ReadLine()
txtExtension.Text = EmployeeData.ReadLine()
txtEmail.Text = EmployeeData.ReadLine()

EmployeeData.Close()
```

Comment: Where is the code for handling the program's response ro the user clicking the "next" button?

Comment: Is that the code in your button's click event? Are you required to use a streamreader?

Comment: Yes, it is a click event.

Comment: Public Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click

Answer (score 1):

You're not reading the file in sequence.

You're opening it once (`EmployeeData = File.OpenText("C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\Assignment 2-1\Assignment 2-1\bin\Debug\Test123.txt")` and then reading one line at a time, closing the file and doing that operation again. You're not moving the buffer ahead or reading the contents other than that.

Try this (or similar):

```
Dim EmployeeData = File.ReadAllLines("PathToFile.txt")
For i As Integer = 0 To 7 Step 8
    txtRecord.Text = (strFileName)
    txtMiddle.Text = EmployeeData(i + 1)
    txtLast.Text = EmployeeData(i + 2)
    txtID.Text = EmployeeData(i + 3)
    txtDepartment.Text = EmployeeData(i + 4)
    txtTelephone.Text = EmployeeData(i + 5)
    txtExtension.Text = EmployeeData(i + 6)
    txtEmail.Text = EmployeeData(i + 7)
Next
```

This will solve your immediate problem (or at least it should, I didn't test it), but wont further your understanding of the concepts (if you're a student). Here's some reading that will help with a little bit with file operations:

[How to: Read Text from a File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.110).aspx)
[File.ReadAllLines Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)
[File Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Read the employee data into a global array one time, when the app loads, like:

```
Public empData() = file.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\Assignment 2-1\Assignment 2-1\bin\Debug\Test123.txt")
```

Establish a counter, also as a global, at that same time:

```
Public empCounter as Integer = 0
```

Then, in your btnNext.Click event, read the values you need and increment the counter:

```
txtMiddle.Text = empData(empCounter * 7 + 0)
txtLast.Text = empData(empCounter * 7 + 1)
txtID.Text = empData(empCounter * 7 + 2)
txtDepartment.Text = empData(empCounter * 7 + 3)
txtTelephone.Text = empData(empCounter * 7 + 4)
txtExtension.Text = empData(empCounter * 7 + 5)
txtEmail.Text = empData(empCounter * 7 + 6)
```

Make tiny tweaks to the above to fit your text file's schema. Also do something about wrapping the counter back to 0 or 1 when you get to the end of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your data (EmployeeData) as in a CSV format then you can do this very easily..... your CSV file will have 8 records like so...

John, Smith, Doe, 10, Development, 02081236456, 123, JSDoe@Yahoo.co.uk

then your code could look something like this.....

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim folder = "<Path to the folder of your Test123.txt file (don't include the file name, just the path up to the folder)>"
    Dim CnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & folder & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using Adp As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Test123.txt]", CnStr)
        Try
            Adp.Fill(dt)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
End Class
```

that displays all the data in a DataGridView.... this is your homework and 'Sir' will know if you wrote it or not, so if you wanna get an 'A+', step thought my code, figure out what's going on  and do the rest....